# Get Ethereum private key from loom private key

Tags: web3js

I deployed my contracts to a local dapp chain with the private key generated by Loom. Since that private key is not compatible with the Ethereum one, I cannot use `web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount` to create an account associated with the address that deployed the contracts. The reason I want to do this is because I have a NodeJS server and I plan to add that account to Web3 wallet so I can call functions with `onlyOwner` modifier from my server. Please let me know if you have the solution to this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually if you use the Loom private key for the `LoomProvider`, the web3 instance will have access to the account that deployed the contract.

```js
const privateKey = LOOM_B64_PRIVATE_KEY;
const publicKey = CryptoUtils.publicKeyFromPrivateKey(
  CryptoUtils.B64ToUint8Array(privateKey),
);

// Create the client
const client = new Client(
  'default',
  'ws://127.0.0.1:46658/websocket',
  'ws://127.0.0.1:46658/queryws',
);

// The address for the caller of the function
const from = LocalAddress.fromPublicKey(publicKey).toString();

const web3 = new Web3(
  new LoomProvider(client, CryptoUtils.B64ToUint8Array(privateKey)),
);
```

Now `account[0]` of the web3 instance will be the contract owner account:

```js
web3.eth.getAccounts().then(account => console.log(account[0]));
```

I was doing this initially but it suddenly started working and not returned `undefined` anymore, lol.